# Does instantiating composite objects instantiate their components in Java

Tags: java, oop, instantiation, composition

This is a design question.

We have magazines that have copies; copies are made of articles. In order for a copy of a magazine to be published, each article needs to be verified; when all articles are verified the copy itself can be published.

So we have a Copy class and an Article class; the Copy class has a "publish" method and the Article class has a "verify" method.

Here are my questions:

1. How do I design the Copy class so that it is composed of Articles?
2. Do I need to instantiate articles separately from the instantiation of the Copy class (and if yes, how do I make the articles part of the copy), or can the instantiation of articles be done by the Copy constructor? Every tutorial deals with "composition versus inheritance" but I was unable to find one that describes instantiation in this case.
3. (Optionally), is there a non-procedural way to write the Copy.publish method so that it only runs if each article has been verified? In my mind there should be some kind of equality of state / simultaneity between the status of each article and the status of the copy (the state of the copy is "can_be_published" when each article has been successfully verified -- but I shouldn't have to check the status of every article, every time one tries to publish a copy).

I'm fairly new to Java and trying to write this little app "by the book" instead of simply writing each operation in a procedural manner, but there's surprisingly little info on composition that I could find.

Comment: I wrote `hava composition` in google. [This was the first result.](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
class Copy {
  private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();
  public addArticle(Article article) {
    this.articles.add(article);
  }
}
```

2.

Yes, you can have an `addArticle` method like above.  However, if you want to enforce the `Copy` having all the articles initially, then you can pass a list of articles into it's constructor instead.

3.

```
class Copy {
  public boolean canPublish() {
    for (Article a: articles)
      if (!article.isVerified())
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: 2: what I'd really like would be to pass a list of strings when instantiating Copy, and have Copy instantiate Article(s) based on those strings. Is it better to instantiate articles outside of Copy, then pass them to the Copy constructor, or do the instantiation of articles inside Copy? Or does it make no difference?

Comment: Better to pass them in, otherwise Copy will begin to have methods that are specific to articles.